# Pass variable from a function to another

Tags: php, laravel, function

I got a controller who has a function who recieve a param and I want to use it to in another function into it, but with no luck for now. How could I do it?

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function viewSlug($slug){ // I recive the variable here
        $book = \Cache::remember('asd',1,function($slug){ // Trying to use the variable here
            return Book::where('slug', str_slug($slug))->firstOrFail();
        });
        $writer = $book->writer;
        return view('bookInfo', ['book' => $book, 'writer' => $writer]);
    }
}
```

Getting

```
"Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\BookController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 0 passed in D:\laragon30\www\books\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\Repository.php on line 327 and exactly 1 expected ◀"
```

Comment: `$slug` is not defined

Comment: The correct thing to do when an answer solves your problem is to Accept it and not delete your question.

Comment: My bad, I'm new here, thanks for the clarification. @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't know Laravel, but just because you define a function to accept an argument doesn't automatically make it passed.  Try `use()`:

```
$book = \Cache::remember('asd',1,function() use($slug){
            return Book::where('slug', str_slug($slug))->firstOrFail();
        });
```

But why a function?

```
$book = \Cache::remember('asd', 1, Book::where('slug', str_slug($slug))->firstOrFail());
```